# GeoJSON without javascript object - can InfoWindow be drawn?

Tags: google-maps, geojson

I'm wondering if an InfoWindow (or similarly rich component) can be handed to a Google Map within the GeoJSON ***itself*** as a "feature", or "shape", etc.

(I'm working in an environment where I don't have access to the `google.maps.Map` object, but I ***do*** have access to the GeoJSON that is rendered on the map.)

In other words, is something like this possible?:

```
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
   {
     "type":"Feature",
     "properties":
     {
       "strokeColor":"#00FF00",
       "strokeWeight":4,
       "strokeOpacity":1
     },
     "geometry":
     {
       "type":"LineString",
       "coordinates":
         [
           [-150.6339948,64.98646889999999],
           [-147.8560028,64.81510162]
         ]
     }
   },
 {
     "type":"Feature",
     "properties":
     {
       "content":"testing testing",
       "minWidth":100
     },
     "geometry":
     {
       "type":"InfoWindow",
       "coordinates":
           [-150.6339948,64.98646889999999]
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: You have to write code to create the InfoWindow.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to add additional data in the JSON response. If so, try making use of `push()` or `unshift()`. Here is a [basic example](https://www.quora.com/I-want-to-add-a-new-JSON-object-to-the-already-existing-JSON-Array-What-are-some-suggestions). There are actually a few ways to go about this, like turning the JSON object to an array first perhaps to make it easier to add data in certain sections. But try to first provide a sample code as StackOverflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: @RickyCuarez thanks, but no, this is a question about GeoJSON specifically. (I know how to alter JSON objects in general.) GeoJSON is a standard for using JSON to draw shapes on maps, and I'm wondering if InfoWindows (a part of that standard) can be added directly to the JSON object, or whether they need to be added programmatically.